# Facebook api '/me' is returning null while using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use facebook php sdk to upload image to the user's album using :

**'/me/photos'** api

I tried it on heroku, and it ran perfectly over there. But now I am trying to use the same code which I used on heroku on my own domain and it is having problem now. The script runs perfectly without any exception or error but the image is not being posted to the user's album.

I am not getting what is the problem over here. Also '/me' api which gives the data of current logged in user is algo returning NULL on my domain and running perfectly when using heroku. I dont know what is the problem over here.
Please someone help!!

Comment: Did you log in to Facebook?

Comment: You need to update the domain in the facebook app developer manager if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @michael yes, the currnt user had already logged into the applicatio..

Comment: @offir ya i updated the domain also.. I have aldo tried lot of solutions already available on this site bt none of them worked for me..